# What is this destructive "entity" that has control of my laptop for 2 years?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have had "something" for about 2 yrs. that no one has been able to help me with.  It started with me reading something on a web page - a story being told in a way that I had to follow along until the end.  That was the shocker.  It was a very personal bit of information that no one other than a few family members would know.  So, then a lot of odd things were showing up and I started to dig.  When I tried to explain to someone they thought I was crazy.

I have had repairs done, told to reset to factory and I would be all set - did that about 6 times and every time, there it was again. Microsoft, Dell support lamely did scans and did not listen to me and found nothing.  All of my - all of ME just got taken away, replaced and I was looking at a Task Mgr. running so many programs... and had many users on my laptop - no clue.

When I ran this Vipre I finally got a list - it was all a log of users trying to get onto my laptop -- thing is, I had over 300 different types of TROJANS, VIRUSES, WORMS -- anything bad - they were the list!  I have no clue why - what the reason is - how to fix it all - but I am so sick and tired of it all.

If I put in a program - like Malware bytes, it would just be disabled, I had no Admin privileges, no control over anything. I tried to explain to so many people, so many times and still I don't know  what it is all about.  I do know, however that it is the same issue that has plagued me, frightened me, taunted me, destroyed all of my pix, docs, laptops.

HELP FROM ANYONE would be greatly appreciated.  FYI - WIN 8, my 2nd new Dell since Christmas.

Comment: This is something nearly impossible for us to answer why this is happening, it is just too broad. It sounds like an account of yours has been hijacked. If you have completely wiped the drive and reinstalled Windows, it should be clean unless you reinstall the software, restore data, or log into an online account that is causing this. Try a complete format and reinstall, like Ziess has suggested below. Do not use the same user name or passwords. Reset all online account passwords, especially the Microsoft Account tied to Windows 8.

Comment: It sounds like you have had quite an ordeal and are understandably tired of rehashing the details.  You posted this question here, presumably to get help rather than just ventilate frustration.  Unfortunately, there are endless possibilities that are covered by your description.  It would take extensive diagnostic information for someone here to do more than guess or suggest generic practices (which aren't considered good answers on SU).  A forum-style site might be a more effective venue for you.  Check out http://windowsforum.com/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your experience, especially with recurrence, I'm inclined to think someone is reinstalling something on your machine every time you reset it or reinstall Windows.  To clarify, were "reset to factory" occurrences full reinstalls from a DVD or freshly downloaded ISO file, or did they use the recovery partition local to your machine (which could easily be compromised by a long-running spybot)?

If the latter, I'd recommend trying a reinstall from DVD media or, better, booting to a Live DVD or USB of a UEFI-compatible Linux distribution and using the tools provided in Linux to completely surface wipe ("mil-spec erase") the hard disk before reinstalling Windows from a fresh download or commercial DVD.  This last should completely solve the problem for you, as long as you take reasonable precautions to prevent a recurrence -- require a password for login, use a non-privileged account for everyday use and a strong password for the admin account, install and run a live malware scanner, or (my preference) do most of the above *and* switch to a Linux distro such as some flavor of Ubuntu as your primary operating system.  Linux helps because most of the malware you're likely to get from amateur hackers is Windows-specific and won't even run in Linux; while there *is* malware specific to Linux, it's less common and mostly confined to servers, where there's potentially something juicy for the attacker to steal.

Meanwhile, if you haven't already, you should proceed on the assumption that your identity has been stolen (in financial terms), since the hacker(s) likely obtained your identifying information, credit card numbers, etc. in the course of your normal use before you learned your machine was infected.  I'm not up to date on what's needed for identity theft, but it's a much more common problem than the level of system infection you're reporting, so there's plenty of information around, and your bank, credit card issuers, etc. should be able to give you some help.